# Why both of if statements are executed no matter what the input is?

Tags: c

In my choose your own adventure, A and B are both inputs that result opening input functions. Whichever is put down, they are both displayed.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char firstname[15];
    char class;
    char swordch0c1;
    char enter;

    printf("Hello there! Could I have your first name?\n");
    scanf("%s",firstname);
    printf("\n---------------------The Legend of %s---------------------",firstname);
    printf("\nPress Enter to continue.");
    enter=getch();
    if(enter=='\n');

    printf("\n\n\nYou are %s, a: \nA.Swordsman\nB.Assassin\nC.Archer\nD.Mage\n",firstname);
    scanf("%c", &class);

    /*swordsman story starts here*/
    if(class=="A");
    {
    printf("\n\nThere you stand, at your boring everyday post.\nWhen you joined the army, you thought                it would be more exciting than this.\nJust then, you see your general walking towards you.");
    printf("\n\nYou quickly improve your posture. \"Soldier, I have an opurtunity for     you\"\nA.\"Really? What is it?\"\nB.\"I'm not interested\"\n");
    scanf("%d",swordch0c1);
    if(swordch0c1=="b");
        {
            printf("\"But... I didn't even tell you what it was. Okay, suit yourself\" You are DOOMED      to a life of boredom.\n\n\n\n\n");
        }
    if(swordch0c1=="a");
        {
            printf("\n\n\n\"Well, you see, there's this dragon. He's been causing big problems.     \nHe's destroyed villages, harrassed the priests on the mountain,\n");
            printf("and even attacked a couple cities. His name is Sorrith, and dozens of knights     have already tried to kill him, none of them being successful.\"");
            printf("\nA.\"Say no more, I'll do it.\"\nB.\"Dragon? No way! You better find someone     else.\nC.\"Keep talking...\"");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I apologize if I'm not specific/clear enough.
I'm using Windows BTW.

Comment: `if(class=="A");` remove the semicolon. But that's just one of many errors in your code. Go read a book.

Comment: 1) `if(class=="A");` --> `if(class=='A')` use `'` and remove `;`

Comment: 2) `scanf("%d",swordch0c1);` --> `scanf(" %c", &swordch0c1);` and `if(swordch0c1=="b");` ditto.

Comment: [-- repeated tip -- ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a few mistake, but this should work!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    char firstname[15], character, swordch0c1, enter;

    printf("Hello there! Could I have your first name?\n>");
    scanf("%s", &firstname);

    printf("\n---------------------The Legend of %s---------------------", firstname);
    printf("\nPress Enter to continue.");
    enter=getch();

    printf("\n\n\nYou are %s, a: \nA.Swordsman\nB.Assassin\nC.Archer\nD.Mage\n>", firstname);
    scanf(" %c", &character);

    /*swordsman story starts here*/
    if (character == 'A') {
        printf("\n\nThere you stand, at your boring everyday post.\nWhen you joined the army, you thought it would be more exciting than this.\nJust then, you see your general walking towards you.");
        printf("\n\nYou quickly improve your posture. \"Soldier, I have an opurtunity for     you\"\nA.\"Really? What is it?\"\nB.\"I'm not interested\"\n>");
        scanf(" %c", &swordch0c1);

        if (swordch0c1 == 'b')
            printf("\"But... I didn't even tell you what it was. Okay, suit yourself\" You are DOOMED      to a life of boredom.\n\n\n\n\n");

        if (swordch0c1 == 'a') {
            printf("\n\n\n\"Well, you see, there's this dragon. He's been causing big problems.     \nHe's destroyed villages, harrassed the priests on the mountain,\n");
            printf("and even attacked a couple cities. His name is Sorrith, and dozens of knights     have already tried to kill him, none of them being successful.\"");
            printf("\nA.\"Say no more, I'll do it.\"\nB.\"Dragon? No way! You better find someone     else.\nC.\"Keep talking...\"");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much! A pointing out of my mistakes would have sufficed, but you went above and beyond!

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the semicolons after each `if` and also use `'` instead of `"` in all the `if(...)` . Also,

```
scanf("%d",swordch0c1);
```

Is wrong as `swordch0c1` is not an `int`. Use `%c` instead of `%d` as it is a `char` that you are scanning

Answer (score 0):

You put semicolons after your both if...

Change `if(swordch0c1=="b");` by `if(swordch0c1=='b')` and `if(swordch0c1=="a");` by `if(swordch0c1=='a')`

I think you should read again your C tutorial or your C book, chapter instruction.

Answer (score 0):

Don't put semicolon after if statement, otherwise it would skipped. Always use single quote for a char, and double for string.